Как получить токен?
Имеется телеграмм бот и когда ты его запускаешь в network имеются запросы и там есть запрос /account в заголовках запроса имеется токен авторизации. Как его можно вытащить? Суть такая, будет расширение и кнопка, при нажатии на нее я хочу найти этот запрос и вытащить токен. Это возможно, потому что таким образом вытягивают ts файлы или же blob. Подскажите пж, как)
